# With which gis technologies was Mapmyrun created?

Tags: online

[www.mapmyrun.com](http://www.mapmyrun.com) is a fantastic online gis application which is slick, fast, reliable and full of interesting tools and functions.

As a GIS developer myself, I am interested in looking into new ways to improve my own applications and utilize new technology (mostly opensource). Does anyone have any inside information about what goes on behind the scenes of mapmyrun? is this a pure googlemaps api app?

Thanks for any replies,

Robert

Comment: Why don't you just ask them?

Comment: looking under 'work for us' shows multiple applications and software used - http://www.mapmyfitnessinc.com/company/work-for-us/ MySQL/PostGIS, Shapely, GEOS, PROJ.4, Openlayers gives a huge hint.